# How to delete record in laravel 5.3 using ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to delete record using ajax in laravel 5.3, i know this is one of the common question and there is already lots of online solutions and tutorials available about this topic. I tried some of them but most of giving me same error `NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed`. I tried to do this task by different angle but i'm stuck and could not found where i'm wrong, that's why i added this question for guideline.

I'm trying following script for deleting the record.

**Controller.php**

```
public function destroy($id)
{   //For Deleting Users
    $Users = new UserModel;
    $Users = UserModel::find($id);
    $Users->delete($id);
    return response()->json([
        'success' => 'Record has been deleted successfully!'
    ]);
}
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/user/delete/{id}', 'UserController@destroy');
```

**In View**

```
<button class="deleteProduct" data-id="{{ $user->id }}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" >Delete Task</button>
```

**App.js**

```
$(".deleteProduct").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var token = $(this).data("token");
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "user/delete/"+id,
            type: 'PUT',
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {
                "id": id,
                "_method": 'DELETE',
                "_token": token,
            },
            success: function ()
            {
                console.log("it Work");
            }
        });

        console.log("It failed");
    });
```

When i'm click on delete button it returning me error `NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed` in console. Without ajax same delete function is working properly.

Can anyone guide me where i'm wrong that i can fix the issue, i would like to appreciate if someone guide me regarding this. Thank You..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of using `Route::get` use `Route::delete`.

In addition to that change the `type: 'Put'` to `type: 'DELETE'` in the ajax call.

---

P.S. This code

```
$Users = new UserModel;        // Totally useless line
$Users = UserModel::find($id); // Can chain this line with the next one
$Users->delete($id);
```

can be written as:

```
UserModel::find($id)->delete();
```

Or even shorter:

```
UserModel::destroy($id);
```

Keep in mind that `->delete()` will fire an event while `::destroy()` will not.

Comment: Thanks for guideline, i followed your instructions but still facing same issue.

Comment: Have you tried using `type: 'DELETE'` in your ajax call?

Comment: Let me check it

Comment: Wow Perfect, Now its working. Thanks a lot for guideline +1

Answer (score 15):

Make sure to add this in the `meta` tag of your view

```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

In your `Routes`, do this

```
Route::delete('/user/delete/{id}', 'UserController@destroy');
```

In your controller, do this

```
UserModel::destroy($id);
```

or

```
DB::table('table_name')->where('id', $id)->delete();
```

Make sure to check that the user who is deleting the account actually owns the account a.k.a run authorization test.

Since it's a `delete` request, you would require to send the `csrf_token` along with your ajax header as the official site states.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Make sure to add this before the ajax call

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
});
```

Now send the request

```
$(".deleteProduct").click(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "user/delete/"+id,
        type: 'delete', // replaced from put
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            "id": id // method and token not needed in data
        },
        success: function (response)
        {
            console.log(response); // see the reponse sent
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
         console.log(xhr.responseText); // this line will save you tons of hours while debugging
        // do something here because of error
       }
    });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".deleteProduct").click(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$.ajax(
{
    url: "user/delete/"+id,
    type: 'DELETE', // Just delete Latter Capital Is Working Fine
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {
        "id": id // method and token not needed in data
    },
    success: function (response)
    {
        console.log(response); // see the reponse sent
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
     console.log(xhr.responseText); // this line will save you tons of hours while debugging
    // do something here because of error
   }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

i'm resuming a working flow of deletion, with a request VERB. Hope it helps

> and theres a commented code in the controller that could handle an ajax request

**In the form (with blade):**

```
  {{ Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['admin.products.edit', $product->id], 'name' => 'delete']) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::delete('admin/products/{id}/edit', ['as' => 'admin.products.edit', 'uses' => 'Product\ProductController@delete']);
```

**ProductController:**

```
 public function delete($id)
    {
        // if (Request::ajax()) {
        // if (Request::isMethod('delete')){

        $item = Product::findOrFail($id);
        $item->delete();

        return redirect()->route('admin.products')->with('flashSuccess', 'deleted');
    }
```

In the redirect part, i'm going back to my list page (admin.products) with a success notifier. The route would be:

```
Route::get('admin/products', ['as' => 'admin.products', 'uses' => 'Product\ProductController@getList']);
```

So you can complete the flow.