# Delete\Add Row with AJAX (Secure way)

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

i am new to Laravel and trying to find way to delete or add row with AJAX request.

Let's say i have PostController and i want to delete one of my post.
So in the PostController there will be destroy function :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Posts::find($id)->delete();
}
```

Now, how i can send from a view AJAX Request to Controller and use this destroy method in secure way.

This works for me,
But the question is if this secure ?

**AJAX Function**

```
function removeRow(id){

    token = $('#rmv').data("token");
    console.log(id);
       $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/posts/"+id,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                "id": id,
                "_method": 'DELETE',
                "_token": token,
            },
            success: function ()
            {
                console.log("it Work");
                $('#post'+id).remove();
            }
        });

}
```

**VIEW**

```
<a id="rmv" onclick="javascript:removeRow({{$post->id}})" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" class="btn btn-primary" >Delete</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete record in laravel 5.3 using ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350918/how-to-delete-record-in-laravel-5-3-using-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0):

OK, This works for me.
But the question is if this secure ?

**AJAX Function**

```
function removeRow(id){

    token = $('#rmv').data("token");
    console.log(id);
       $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/posts/"+id,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                "id": id,
                "_method": 'DELETE',
                "_token": token,
            },
            success: function ()
            {
                console.log("it Work");
                $('#post'+id).remove();
            }
        });

}
```

**VIEW**

```
<a id="rmv" onclick="javascript:removeRow({{$post->id}})" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" class="btn btn-primary" >Delete</a>
```

Comment: You could encode or hash `id` to make it more secure