# Delete my database record using routes in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, http-delete

I'm using Laravel and I'm trying to achieve a delete function that takes care of deleting the selected task the user made.

**I was wondering how can I achieve this using routes?**

```
<a href="{{ route("tasks.edit", ["id" => $task->id]) }}"><button class="btn btn-outline-light">Edit</button></a> 
<a href="{{ route("tasks.destroy", ["id" => $task->id]) }}"><button class="btn btn-outline-light">Delete</button></a>
```

At this moment my delete route takes me to the same page as what the edit route does.

**My delete function:**

```
    public function destroy(Task $task)
{
    $task->delete();
    return redirect('/tasks')->with('success', 'Task removed');
}
```

I got a working delete function using the Laravel forms:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['TasksController@destroy', $task->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class'=> 'float-right']) !!}
 {{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
 {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-outline-danger'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Is it worth to consider another method of taking care of my deletes or should I stick with using the Laravel forms?

Comment: You're likely looking for javascript. Ajax type of request.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of CSRF protection. You may think using an ajax request.
You can find an example in this post.
[How to delete record in laravel 5.3 using ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350918/how-to-delete-record-in-laravel-5-3-using-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0):

When you press the delete link, you'll be basically making a GET request to the tasks.destroy route, which is not what you want. You can either create a form and submit it on click (the laravel logout btn does something similar)

```
<a href="#" 
    onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('task-destroy-form').submit();">
    Delete task
</a>
<form id="task-destroy-form" action="{{ route("tasks.destroy", ["id" => $task->id]) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
</form>
```

or make an ajax call that will send the id and CSRF parameters to the route.