# How to insert data using ajax with id and without using forms in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I try to insert data using id in my url like this.

```
<a href="{{route('absent',$User->id)}}">absent</a>                                                   
<a href="{{route('present',$User->id)}}">present</a>
```

My route is:

```
Route::get('/present/{id}', 'UserController@present')->name('present');
Route::get('/absent/{id}', 'UserController@absent')->name('absent');
```

Route is working. but the page is loading, I try to insert data without loading. I know how to insert data using ajax HTML form way. but how to insert using id use ajax?

Comment: you can use form, and submit through ajax

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert data without reloading you have to bind JavaScript functions to the HTML links you specified. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350918/how-to-delete-record-in-laravel-5-3-using-ajax-request) is different but you can use the same approach to achieve your need.

Answer (score 0):

I propose, that you change your anchor tags to buttons and add a class to them and save their routing endpoints in data attributes:

```
<button class="action_buttons" data-route="{{route('absent', $User->id)}}">absent</button>
<button class="action_buttons" data-route="{{route('present', $User->id)}}">present</a>
```

And, then use JQuery event handling to detect when they are clicked and then simply use Ajax to get the related route from the button's data attribute and send a GET request to that route:

```
$('.action_buttons').on('click', function(){

    // Get the route data from the tag.
    let route = $(this).data('route');

    $.ajax({
        url: route,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        }
    });
});
```